# multi text node manipulation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have the following html structure:

```
<ol>
<li>
    Text A <span>Other text</span>, Text B
</li>
<li>
    Text A <span>Other text</span>, Text B
</li>
</ol>
```

How do I iterate through each list item using jQuery and change the text for both Text A and Text B individually without disturbing the span and it's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("ol li").contents().filter(function() { 
  return this.nodeType === 3;}
);
```

in other words [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4axxxzrb/):

```
$("ol li").contents().filter(function() { 
  return this.nodeType === 3;}
).each(function(i, obj){
  //your code using i, obj or this for choose
  this.textContent = "change";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The only thing this does not address is that the text for Text A and Text B need to be different. What does that look like?